# How to run python script in linux terminal console and continue using command line?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, command-line

My question seems to be quite easy, but for some reason I did not find a quick answer to it. I have a python script that I want to run on the terminal command line (Ubuntu linux server), which works for me. But then I can't use the command line until the script ends. The script takes a long time to run, and I would like to continue using the command line to perform other tasks. How can you do the work of a script when its progress is not shown on the command line, but keep its work? And how can I see the active processes that are running on the server to see if a process is running?

Run script command:
`python script.py`

Add next with `& echo "123"`:

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a `linux` thing which runs a program in the background whilst you continue with the command prompt?

Comment: @quamrana, I am not a very confident Linux user, logically this should be all, but I still can’t figure it out in any way

Comment: Add ampersand `&` at the end of your command to make it run in background. So basically just use `python script.py &`

Comment: @PankajSaini, Something does not work, all the same, all the information from the script is displayed in the console. Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The script takes a long time to run, and I would like to continue
> using the command line to perform other tasks.

It seems that you want to run said process in background, please try pasting following

```
python script.py &
echo "123"
```

it should start your `script.py` and then output `123` (without waiting until `script.py` ends)

> how can I see the active processes that are running on the server to
> see if a process is running?

Using [`ps`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) command

```
ps -ef
```

will list all processes which you would probably want to filter to get interested one to you.

Comment: hmm, strange, the script still outputs everything to the console and does not allow you to write something third-party. Tried to use ```bg``` for process and result is still the same

Comment: @kostyaivanov you did not specified that your `script.py` is making use of standard output, in such case you might redirect standard output to file in order to inspect it after script finish, for example `python script.py > file.txt &`